# Nginx - Conflicting server name issue & redirection loop

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

What I am simply trying to achieve is to redirect any request to my website (e.g. from `example.com` or `www.example.com` or `http://example.com`) to `https://www.example.com`.

However, with the current configuration, I get a redirection loop and an warning.

The warning is:

> [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored.

My configuration file:

```
    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com;
    }


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;


    #redirect non www to www.
  return 301 https://www.example.com;

 #  root /home/forge/example.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/140111/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/140111/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/example.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    #cache:
    location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 168h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }


}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    root /home/forge/example.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/140111/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/140111/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/example.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    #cache:
    location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 168h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

}


# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/after/*;
```

**What I've tried**

I have googled this question and came across a few answers. I have tried going to `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and looking for any files named `default~` but there were none.

I am getting an endless loop from this code. No idea why.

Comment: Can you please post the config, if any, from `forge-conf/example.com/before/`, `include forge-conf/example.com/after/`, and `include forge-conf/example.com/server/` ?

Comment: possibly related question... http://stackoverflow.com/q/26815723

Comment: Please try to find the files that contain `www.example.com`, like `grep -inr www.example.com /etc/nginx`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this config to redirect all the http requests to https and move all the non-www requests

I use this on my server configurations and they are working perfectly.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.example.com  example.com;

# Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
return 302 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443;
server_name example.com;
include /etc/nginx/conf-available/ssl.conf;

# Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
return 302 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}


 server {
listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

server_name www.example.com;

include /etc/nginx/conf-available/ssl.conf;
```

and if you are using Wordpress then don't forget to change your website address in genral settings.

For more information read this post.
[how to redirect non-www url to www for wordpress in Nginx and Apache?](https://www.debyum.com/how-to-redirect-non-www-url-to-www-for-wordpress-in-nginx/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single server block for HTTP/HTTPS like this

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   443 default_server ssl;

    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate        /path/to/my/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/my/key;

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

[Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my issue arose because I had an extra file in the sites-enabled directory. When I was editing with nano it made a .save file...

Thus trying to load the same files twice..